# Mapping spring configuration to integration flows

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I have a Spring Boot / Integration app whose integration flows begin with RabbitMQ queues. The flows themselves and the app in general are working well, but there's a lot of redundant configuration for the initial inbound AMQP configuration.

At the moment I have ten `DataType`s, each with slightly varying properties, some of which need to be defined at runtime. I initialize an inbound flow for each, set a couple of headers, and quickly dump them into a common channel for processing.

The Java configuration for just *one* of the `NetworkDiagnostic` `DataType` looks like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundNetworkDiagnosticFlow(@Qualifier("connectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    @Qualifier(BeanNames.INBOUND_EVENTS_CHANNEL) MessageChannel outbound,
                                                    @Qualifier(BeanNames.JSON_NODE_MESSAGE_CONVERTER) MessageConverter messageConverter,
                                                    @Qualifier("networkDiagnosticQueue") Queue queue,
                                                    @Value("${networkDiagnostic.numConsumers}") int numConsumers,
                                                    @Value("${networkDiagnostic.prefetchCount}") int prefetchCount) {
    return makeEventIntegrationFlow(connectionFactory, outbound, messageConverter, queue, numConsumers, prefetchCount,
            DataTypes.EVENT_NETWORK_DIAGNOSTIC);

}

@Bean
public Binding networkDiagnosticBinding(@Qualifier("networkDiagnosticQueue") Queue queue) {
    return makeFanoutBinding(queue, NETWORK_DIAGNOSTIC_EXCHANGE_NAME);
}


@Bean
public Queue networkDiagnosticQueue() {
    return makeQueue(NETWORK_DIAGNOSTIC_QUEUE_STRING);
}

@Bean
public FanoutExchange networkDiagnosticExchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange(NETWORK_DIAGNOSTIC_EXCHANGE_NAME);
}
```

There is parallel configuration for another nine. I would like to factor this out more, so that a) repetition is removed, and b) more inputs would be configurable simply from a configuration file on a server.

My general thought is that I would have a yaml configuration file:

```
data_types:
   - name: network-diagnostic
     schema: event
     window_type: hourly
     exchange_name: blahblahblah
     queue_name: blahblahblah
     ...
   - name: log-diagnostic
   ...
```

which, via `@ConfigurationProperties` I'd map to a class more or less like:

```
 /**
 * Organizes information and configuration for a DataType
 */
public class DataType {
    private String name;
    private Schema schema;
    private WindowType windowType;
    private long bucketLength;

    private String exchange;
    private String routingKey;
    ...
```

And that I'd need some method -- `registerAllBeans` -- expecting all of the DataTypes, which creates all of the necessary beans (and their interrelationships), and calls  `SingletonBeanRegistry::registerSingleton` on each.

That said, I'm unsure when that method should run, and how to get it to run then. On the one hand, I need it to run once the beans created by  configuration properties are accessible, but before life cycle management is started (so my integration flows will be managed), and preferably before `RabbitAdmin::afterPropertiesSet` so I can also get the implicit declaration of my RabbitMQ objects.

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**: I followed @ArtemBilan's advice from below and was able to code a mock example, which I'm including here.

A main class of:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoApplication.class);
        parentBuilder.child(ChildConfiguration.class).properties("name=bob", "message='hi how are you?'").run();
        parentBuilder.child(ChildConfiguration.class).properties("name=jane", "message='hi how are you?'").run();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
        Object object = new Object();
        return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
                .handle(m -> System.out.println(object + " " + m.getPayload() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .get();
    }
}
```

A child config of:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Sample.class)
@Configuration
public class ChildConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow anotherOutgoingFlow(Sample sample) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(() -> new GenericMessage<>("hello " + sample.getName() + "; " + sample.getMessage()),
                        m -> m.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(500)))
                .channel("inputChannel")
                .get();
    }
}
```

And a model class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Sample {
    private String name;
    private String message;

    public Sample() { }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

prints, for example:

```
2016-03-25 17:12:04.109  INFO 24637 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 0.169 seconds (JVM running for 3.878)
java.lang.Object@25c4da11 hello bob; 'hi how are you?' 1458940324438
java.lang.Object@25c4da11 hello jane; 'hi how are you?' 1458940324607
java.lang.Object@25c4da11 hello bob; 'hi how are you?' 1458940324938
java.lang.Object@25c4da11 hello jane; 'hi how are you?' 1458940325108
java.lang.Object@25c4da11 hello bob; 'hi how are you?' 1458940325439
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use `parent/child` architecture for your application, when you will be able to reuse your template configuration based on the provided environment.

See [Spring Boot Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-fluent-builder-api) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit more? If I understand you, I'd have a main which passes the top level config as the parent, and creates a child context for each `DataType` -- which makes sense -- but I'm unclear how I can have reference to objects defined by `ConfigurationProperties` at that time -- are not those objects defined once there's already an application context?

Comment: M-m-m. No, if you use `@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataType.class)` in the proper place in your child application context sources.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but you seem to be suggesting a means of swapping out bean definitions based on environment -- swapping out one set of DataTypes for another -- but my problem is how to define multiple convergent integration flows in a single environment based on config at runtime.

Comment: OK. Maybe we don't understand each other. So, I'd be glad to hear from other guys on the matter. For me that looks like genric `@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataType.class)` on some `@Configuration` class, which you use as a resource for child context and provide for it the particular `environment` based on the concrete `data-type` after the parsing that from the collection from the top level `application.yml`.

Comment: That makes a little more sense to me. I'm going to give that a try -- thanks, Artem.

Comment: I got a proof of concept for myself (shown above). Seems a bit heavy weight of a solution, but it definitely gets the job done (and I've learned a new trick!). Thanks.